# for loop in a batch file with sql statement

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I have written the batch file to print out max(ID) from sql server. I see for loop, looping through twice, once printing the correct iD number and in next iteration prints a bracket '('. I have no clue why it is iterating twice.

```
@echo on 
set maxid=0
echo %maxid%
timeout /t 10
for /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%i in (`sqlcmd -E -S "DBNAME\instance01" -h-1 -Q "select max(ID) from table1"`) do set maxid=%%i
echo testingcount 
echo %maxid%
timeout /t 10
if %maxid% NEQ 0 (
echo count not zero
echo %maxid%
timeout /t 10
goto end
) else if %maxid% EQU 0(
echo count is zero
timeout /t 10
}
:end
echo END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have been getting a part of the output that you didn't want (`(1 row(s) affected)`. Try this instead:

```
@echo off
set maxid=0
echo %maxid%
timeout /t 10
for /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%i in (`sqlcmd -E -S "DBNAME\instance01" -h-1 -Q "set nocount on;select max(id) from table1"`) do set maxid=%%i
echo testingcount 
echo %maxid%
timeout /t 10

if %maxid% GTR 0 (
    echo count not zero
    echo %maxid%
    timeout /t 10
    goto end
) else (
    if %maxid% EQU 0 (
        echo count is zero
        timeout /t 10
    )
)
:end
echo END
```